# How to test a function passed as a prop to child using React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

In my React application, I am using functional componet with hook & React Testing Library for testing. Need to test a function which is passed as prop to child, the code is as below

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function FileUploadContainer() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useContext(Context);
  
  const uploadFile = async (file, index) => {
    // Code
  };

  const cancelUpload = async (index) => {
    // Cancel Code
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
          <FileUploadContainerComponent
            files={state.fileList}
            cancelUpload={cancelUpload}
            uploadFile={uploadFile}
          />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

I am new to React Testing Libray, any help/input appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to test the `FileUploadContainerComponent`'s `cancelUpload` and `uploadFile` props you can achieve that with [`jest.fn()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestfnimplementation).

An example of what your test would look like:

```js
it('Should call cancelUpload', () => {
  const mockCancelUpload = jest.fn();
  const { /* RTL queries */ } = render(
    <FileUploadContainerComponent cancelUpload={mockCancelUpload} />
  );

  // Trigger your cancelUpload function with the correct queries

  // Assert if the function was called
  expect(mockCancelUpload).toHaveBeenCalled();
  // ...
})
```

As you are using async functions as props make sure to check out other [methods](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api) on the mock function that will help you with that.